# How to reduce JAVA applications CPU usage?

Tags: java, linux, performance, jvm

There are two Java processes (A, B) on a Linux machine (CentOS 6.5 64bit). A sends lots of binary data to B using sockets. B writes data to disk. Per second 50-100MB data are written to disk. On a quad core processor, the CPU is nearly 100% used. Previously we ran a similar application but written by C, only 25% of CPU was used.

We had done a lot of tuning. We learned that there were some bugs of epoll, then we upgraded JDK version to 1.8. We also did some JVM tuning. Now the total CPU usage is lower than before, but we are not satisfied. We think we can reduce it more.

There are lots of data written to disk. We believe that the disk is not the bottleneck. Because we use a large RAID. We ran the similar application written by C with much more disk bandwidth before, and everything was OK.

But we also find a problem. When the kernel is flushing dirty data to disks, the CPU usage will be very high. So we increase /proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_ratio in order to do asynchronous flushing as much as possible. After we change the value, it seems to work, but after a while, then the high CPU problem comes again.

Can we do more performance tuning for Java applications with high IO bandwidth?

Comment: RAID-what exactly, are we talking striping or mirroring.The latter won't help with disk throughput. And don't think SATA3 speeds are what you get from the actual disk, even a 10K RPM grunter disk on my most powerful system maxes out at about 150M/s sustained throughput.

Comment: Maybe it's the sockets code. Impossible to say without seeing it.

Comment: Or using naive stream I/O instead of something like NIO.

Comment: @chrylis How exactly would that cause 100% CPU usage? Unless they're reading a byte at a time, which is avoidable without NIO.

Comment: I said "naive". Perhaps not wrapping in a buffer.

Comment: If your CPU usage is high, you need to figure out what the cause is and fix it. For performance I would use sockets between machines, but prefer shared memory when on the same machine. If you can't do that, have A and B run in the same process and remove the CPU over head, at least to see what would happen if it's not there,

Comment: It doesn't sound like the high CPU usage is in your program so whether you use C or Java won't make much difference.

Comment: We  use striping. More than 12 disks.

Comment: Which RAID level are you using? If RAID 5 or 6, run a test using RAID 0 instead as this will likely increase your storage performance significantly (depending on hardware). Since your issue arises when dirty data flushing occurs, your storage performance definitely could be the problem. Also, increasing /proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_ratio is just postponing the inevitable flushing. Try reducing it instead, to hopefully induce more frequent but smaller flush operations.

Comment: @flypen If you're not going to post code this question is off topic.

Answer (score 1):

Before you can do performance tuning you need to find out what's dominating the CPU time.

This is a multi-faceted topic, you'll have to look at what the kernel is doing, which system calls are issued at what rate, what are your access patterns, how do file systems and other storage layers affect the characteristics of various file system operations etc.

Netflix recently presented a way to [get full kernel/userspace/java stacks](http://techblog.netflix.com/2015/07/java-in-flames.html), that might be a useful starting point, but there are many other things to monitor.